# Munchkins: Apocolypse Preparing for the 7th seal

Tags: munchkin

Ok, so we are mid-game and the pressure is thick. My so called "friend", has been stealing all my small items the entire game. The host of tonights game has favored his apocolypse doors for every knock, and consequently this game is nearing the 7th seal. For those of you that know, this is the hail mary Game Over play. My thief of a friend does a quick count of his combat bonuses and then whispers to me, "we are tied for first...." I didn't come here to split the glory. Once the disaster that flips up the 7th seal is played, I try to equip some items for a bonus.

May I equip cards to "buffer" my combat bonus, in response to the apocolypse 7th seal attempt to open?

Comment: Interesting question. I have to look up the rules, what they say at which time you can play items, but it might well be that you can anytime except combat.

Answer (score 3):

OK, I looked up the [rules](http://www.worldofmunchkin.com/rules/apoc_rules.pdf). On page 5 is a section called 'WHEN TO PLAY CARDS'. In it you find:

> **Items – Playing Them**
>
> Any Item card may be played to the table as soon as you get it, or at
>   any time on your own turn other than in combat (unless the card itself
>   says otherwise).

So, if you have no combat and it is your own turn, you can play item cards.